# return all rows for 5 columns in SQlite database

Tags: android

I use the following code to get one column only of the database on array and display it

```
public ArrayList<String> dbtoArr() {
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String q = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE 1";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) != null) {
                arr.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        return arr;
    }
```

i want to retrieve all rows for all columns

i don't know any object in android that can carry this kind of data

suppose if i have 5 or more columns how i would carry them?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you not create an object with the columns as fields and then return an ArrayList of the objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a POJO(Plain Old Java Object) class, and have a method where you pass in the Cursor and assign each property with its value.

Something like this:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    ...
    public Person(Cursor c) {
        name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("age"));        
        ...
    }
}
```

And then, instead of having an ArrayList of Strings, you'll have an ArrayList of Persons

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
...
while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
    Person p = new Person(c);
    persons.add(p);
}
```

Comment: oh thanks i lost my mind this solution was very easy i totally forget it

Comment: I'm glad It was helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with member variables declared each corresponding to your column. Let's name it `MyClass`.
Then you need to set the values to the member variables in your database method and return the list of objects created .

```
   public ArrayList<MyClass> dbtoArr() {
        ArrayList<MyClass> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String q = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE 1";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) != null) {
                arr.add(new MyClass().setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"))));
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        return arr;
    }
```